# One button to fire toggle functions? Press button -> toggleOn(), press again -> toggleOff(), press again -> toggleOn()

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to use the same `onClick` from a button to make it a "toggle"?

I have a button, `<button>Toggle</button>` and basically toggling it on should execute either `toggleOn()` or `toggleOff()`.

How do I do this with just `onClick` property?

Comment: it should execute `toggle` and `toggle` should decide if the toggle is on or off ... `HTMLElement.dataset` can help here to store current state

Answer (score 1):

You will need to maintain some state as to whether the button is "on" or "off".  I would do this by creating a closure over a `buttonState` variable:

```js
const setText = ( text ) => () => {
    document.getElementById('toggled').innerHTML = text;
};

const toggleOff = setText('off');
const toggleOn = setText('on');

const makeClickhandler = () => {
        let buttonState = false;
        return () => {
            buttonState ? toggleOff() : toggleOn();
            buttonState = !buttonState;
        }
    };
    
document.getElementById('yourbuttonid').addEventListener('click', makeClickhandler());
```

```html
<button id='yourbuttonid'>Toggle</button>
<span id='toggled'>off</span>
```

Comment: This doesn't handle context and arguments properly, which is crucial for event handlers

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple "toggler" higher-order function:

```
function toggler(fn1, fn2) {
  var toggled = true;
  return function () {
    toggled = !toggled;
    return (toggled ? fn1 : fn2).apply(this, arguments);
  }
}

function logToConsole (e) {
  console.log(this, e);
}

function logToAlert (e) {
  alert(e);
}

var toggledLog = toggler(logToConsole, logToAlert);
```

Now running `toggledLog` with arguments and context will work properly. You can use it in your `onClick` handler.

Answer (score 0):

I can imagine different ways to achieve it.

The first to come to my mind would be something like:

```js
var button = document.getElementById('toggle');
var state = document.getElementById('current-state');

button.addEventListener("click", toggleState);

function toggleState() {
  if ( button.dataset.state == "on" ) {
    button.dataset.state = "off";
    state.innerHTML = "I'm off"; 
  } else {
    button.dataset.state = "on";
    state.innerHTML = "I'm on"; 
  }
}
```

```html
<button id="toggle" data-state="off">Toggle me!</button>

<div id="current-state">I'm off</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A similar but slightly more compact approach to Alex Young's:

```js
function toggleOn() {
  console.log( 'on' );
}

function toggleOff() {
  console.log( 'off' );
}

var button = document.getElementById( 'button' );

button.addEventListener( 'click', function clickToggle() {
  clickToggle.state = !clickToggle.state;
  clickToggle.state ? toggleOn() : toggleOff();
} );
```

```html
<button id="button">Toggle</button>
```

This uses the fact that you can attach properties to named functions this way. I'm not sure what the exact terminology for this is.

---

To address Joe Frambach's valid concerns, addressed in the comments, you could change it to:

```
button.addEventListener( 'click', function clickToggle() {
  clickToggle.state = !clickToggle.state;
  return ( clickToggle.state ? toggleOn : toggleOff ).apply( this, arguments );
} );
```

Comment: This doesn't handle context and arguments properly, which is crucial for event handlers

Comment: @JoeFrambach I'm not sure what you mean by that. Can you explain what you mean?

Comment: When you attach an event to a button like `<button onClick="doThis">`, you'd like to gather information about the clicked element, perhaps the mouse position, perhaps if a ctrl/alt key is held, etc. An event handler gets context via `this` variable, and event information via arguments. Try logging `this` and arguments in `toggleOn` and `toggleOff` in your code.

Comment: @JoeFrambach So, just add the `event` argument. I left it out for brevity, since I don't use it in the handler. I don't see the problem. Or am I missing something else?

Comment: @JoeFrambach O, I see now. Well, then just call the functions like `toggleOn.call( this );`, etc.

Comment: Yes see my answer

Comment: @JoeFrambach Yes, fair enough.